# "JVM startup" error while starting Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, java-7, eclipse-indigo

Running latest SR of Indigo on Win7SP1.

One thing that I find frustrating sometimes is that Eclipse sometimes fails immediately on startup with a "JVM startup" error. It gives me a dialog with the Java command line, and just says it exited with code 1.

Up to today, I was able to start Indigo from my desktop shortcut using JDK 1.70_25. This morning I changed my ini file to reference 1.7.0_40 and restarted it. It failed immediately with that JVM startup error. It doesn't even write anything into the workspace log file.

However, if I first run a Windows cmd and then just paste the contents of my shortcut, it's able to start up without error.

It would really be nice if I could get some better diagnostics when it fails.

Here is my current STS.ini (Using SpringSource Toolkit):

```
    -vm 
C:/eclipse/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
-startup 
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library 
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product 
com.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vmargs
-debug
-Xverify:none
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xmn128m
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
```

Here's the Eclipse shortcut:

```
C:\eclipse\springsource\sts-2.8.0.RELEASE\STS.exe -showlocation -data "c:\Users\<myuid>\workspace6"
```

And here is my PATH:

```
C:\Users\<myuid>\frameworks\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\eclipse\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;C:\Cygwin\home\<myuid>\bin;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\frameworks\db-derby-10.5.3.0-bin\bin;C:\Cygwin\home\<myuid>\bin;C:\Cygwin\home\<myuid>;C:\Users\<myuid>\frameworks\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\eclipse\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;C:\Cygwin\home\<myuid>\bin;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\frameworks\db-derby-10.5.3.0-bin\bin;C:\Cygwin\usr\local\bin;C:\Cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files\Voltage Security\Voltage SecureFile;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Enterprise Vault\EVClient;C:\Program Files\Code Collaborator Client;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Voltage Security\Voltage SecureMail;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Voltage Security;C:\users\<myuid>\frameworks\phantomjs-1.9.0-windows;C:\Program Files\ATT Connect\OutlookAddin\Outlook;C:\Users\<myuid>\frameworks\sonar-runner-2.3\bin;C:\Users\<myuid>\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Cygwin\bin;C:\Cygwin\bin;C:\Cygwin\lib\lapack;C:\frameworks\jaxb-ri-20081030\bin;C:\frameworks\pmd-bin-4.3\bin;C:\Users\<myuid>\workspace4\WorkTreeConfig\target;C:\Users\<myuid>\sysinternals\junction;C:\Users\<myuid>\frameworks\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin;C:\frameworks\jaxb-ri-20081030\bin;C:\frameworks\pmd-bin-4.3\bin;C:\Users\<myuid>\workspace4\WorkTreeConfig\target;C:\Users\<myuid>\sysinternals\junction;C:\Users\<myuid>\frameworks\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin
```

Comment: can you post your eclipse.ini, your windows path and your eclipse shortcut definition values? This would better help diagnose your problem

Comment: Indigo is very old now... you should strongly consider upgrading to Juno or Kepler. Some issue like this probably *wont* be fixed because it's a non-issue with the later releases.

Comment: I'm well aware of the available versions.  When Emacs+ is finally somewhat usable in Kepler SR1 (allowing chorded key sequences), I'll probably upgrade to the corresponding STS release.

Answer (score 0):

It's very is very annoying when you get to spend something like it, maybe [this guide](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html) can helps you.

Comment: Changing from "javaw" to "java" might help.  Ironically, when I changed this, it didn't fail to start up. :( I guess I'll try it again going back and see if it still fails.

Comment: Someone downvoted my question, not your answer, if that's what you're concerned about.  I wonder the same thing, but I'm not going to worry about it.